# how can I validate and process html form (taking in inpute from the ui login interface) using fiber framework golang programming language

Tags: html, node.js, json, go, go-fiber

please help me to take input with fiber golang framework

````
<form action="/" method="POST" novalidate>
    <div>
        <p><label>Your email:</label></p>
        <p><input type="email" name="email"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><label>Your message:</label></p>
        <p><textarea name="content"></textarea></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send message">
    </div>
</form> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `c.FormValue` for simple forms, and keep in mind that the return value is always a string. So if you want to send integers as well you will have to manually convert them to integers in handlers. for more complex forms like sending files you can use `c.MultipartForm`.

```
func main() {
    // create new fiber instance  and use across whole app
    app := fiber.New()

    // middleware to allow all clients to communicate using http and allow cors
    app.Use(cors.New())

    // homepage
    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // rendering the "index" template with content passing
        return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{})
    })

    // app.Post because method="POST"
    // "/" because action="/"
    app.Post("/", handleFormUpload)

    // start dev server on port 4000
    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":4000"))
}

func handleFormUpload(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    email := c.FormValue("email")
    content := c.FormValue("content")

    fmt.Println(email, content)
    return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"status": 201, "message": "Created!"})
}
```